# Unable to trigger JavaScript method from code-behind using Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, scriptmanager, registerclientscriptblock

Issue details:

After saving the data in DB, I need to show an alert to the user.
For this, I have **registered the script** from code-behind.
But it is **NOT working with update-panel** whereas it works as expected without update-panel.
I need  to make it work with update-panel.

I tried by adding `$(document).ready(function ()` while registering the script, but it didn't work.

Then, I tried with `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` method instead of `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()`, but it also didn't work.

Here is the code snippet of web page (ASPX):

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Button ID="btnOutsideUpdatePanel" runat="server" Text="Outside UpdatePanel" OnClick="btnOutsideUpdatePanel_Click" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnInsideUpdatePanel" runat="server" Text="Inside UpdatePanel" OnClick="btnInsideUpdatePanel_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <uc1:Child runat="server" id="Child1" />
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc1:Child runat="server" id="Child2" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is the code snippet of user-control (ASCX):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Child.ascx.cs" Inherits="UpdatePanelAndScript.Child" %>
<asp:Button ID="btnUserControl" runat="server" Text="User Control" OnClick="btnUserControl_Click" />
```

Code-behind of web-page:

```
protected void btnOutsideUpdatePanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowSuccess", "alert('Hi');", true);
}

protected void btnInsideUpdatePanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowSuccess", "alert('Hi');", true);
}
```

Code-behind of user-control:

```
protected void btnUserControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowSuccess", "alert('Hi');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change the following statement:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
(
    this.GetType(),
    "ShowSuccess",
    "alert('Hi');",
    true
);
```

To:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
(
    this,
    this.GetType(),
    "ShowSuccess",
    "alert('Hi');",
    true
);
```

Reference:

- [MSDN ScriptManager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx)

> **Registering Partial-Page Update Compatible Scripts**
>   [...] If you are rendering script for use inside an UpdatePanel control, make sure that you call the methods of the ScriptManager control.

Comment: Yes, it worked in the above code snippet.
Thanks
But, after integrating it in the actual code-base it is NOT working as expected (It is working partially)..

Issue Description:

I have an AJAX file-uploader control inside update panel.
Case 1:
When I add the update-panel property "updateMode='conditional'", the popup works as expected.
But the control that is kept outside of update-panel doesn't get render after partial-postback. 
Case 2:
And I remove the update-panel property "updateMode='conditional'", the popup DOESN'T work at all
i.e. the script doesn't get register in the DOM.

Comment: _"But the control that is kept outside of update-panel doesn't get render after partial-postback"_. Is your control generated dynamically? Can you provide the required code to reproduce your issue?