# After partial postback of Update-panel, everything outside the update-panel disappears

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, updatepanel, scriptmanager

Issue Description:

I have an **AJAX file-uploader control inside update panel**. 
After successful file-upload, I need to show a bootstrap popup to the user.

**Case 1**: When I add the update-panel property "updateMode='conditional'", the popup works as expected after successful file-upload. But the control that is kept outside of update-panel doesn't get render after partial-postback. 
I am using the following code-base to trigger the JavaScript code from code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "AddStudent",
    "addStudent('1','xyz','10000');",true);
```

**Case 2**: But when I remove the "updateMode='conditional'" property, the controls outside the update-panel doesn't disappear after partial postback but the popup DOESN'T work at all i.e. the script doesn't get register in the DOM.

Kindly help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to trigger JavaScript method from code-behind using Update Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788655/unable-to-trigger-javascript-method-from-code-behind-using-update-panel)

Comment: This question looks a lot like another question of yours.

Comment: Not at all.. Earlier I was unable to trigger the JavaScript method from code-behind. Now, I am able to but the controls outside of update panel disappears after partial postback. Probably the issue is with AJAX uploader. It works fine when I remove AJAX upoader from update-panel. Hope you understand the difference. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the file upload control does *not* work inside an update panel.

Comment: @VDWWD: Kindly go through the answer posted by me. Hopefully now you will understand that the question was not duplicated and will remove the "duplicate tag" and "-1" point from this question as well. With due respect, I am saying that, I do post my queries here seeking for help from the intellectuals. I always make sure that I should not put garbage here. Thanks Folk!

Answer (score 1):

After digging out each & every line of code, finally I got the reason behind the bug.

A "div" tag that was placed inside update-panel was NOT closed as expected.
Here is the error & the solution:

**Erroneous tag:**

```
<div class="vertical-bar"/>
```

**Solution:**

```
<div class="vertical-bar"></div>
```

As the above DIV was NOT closed correctly, the DOM was under an impression that all the elements below the div, are inside the div and as a result all the controls was getting rendered inside update-panel.

Hence, in the process of partial-postback the other controls were getting disappeared.